# How to write a batch file to rename multiple files which filename contains more than 2 period?

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I have three picture in a folder, named 1.jpg.jpg 2.jpg.jpg and 3.jpg.jpg

How to write a batch file to rename them into 1.jpg 2.jpg and 3.jpg?

I used REN *.jpg.jpg *.jpg  but it didn't work

Comment: which os are you using?

Comment: `for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B *.jpg.jpg') do ren "%%a" "%%~Na"`

Answer (score 1):

```
ren *.jpg.jpg *.
```

This will simply remove the *last* extension (in fact, the last one is the only extension, the *first one* is part of the file name)

Comment: @Aacini, the `*.` in the target mask is greedy, copying all characters from input name up to the last dot instance and nothing more. That way the extension is removed, and the `.jpg` that now ends the file name (the previous first *extension*) becomes the new extension of the file.